# Visual Studio 2010 Bex error

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm creating a project in asp.net (framework 4.0). While opening the project in Visual Studio 2010 I'm causing this problem.

[image]

Comment: This is not a programming relative question, and what have to do with asp.net ? Maybe to contact microsoft and send there the report ? - Clear the *.suo file that is together with the .sln file and try to open it again.

Comment: Well, it is a programming question, and would be on-topic for this site, except that there aren't enough details provided in the question to answer it.